# redirect error exception array to string conversion Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes, destroy

im trying to redirect my delete function back to index page that have parameter team. but it keeps throwing me Error Exception array to string conversion.
here my index fucntion on MonitorController.php

```
public function index(Team $team)
{   

    $team = Team::where('id',$team->id)->first();

    $objective = Objective::with('keyresult')
                    ->where('team_id',$team->id)
                    ->get();
                    
    $objective = Objective::with('task')
                    ->where('team_id',$team->id)
                    ->get();

    $objective = Objective::with('deadline')
                    ->where('team_id',$team->id)
                    ->get();
    
    return view('/sistem/monitor/index', compact('objective','team'));   
}
```

and here is my delete function inside the same file MonitorController.php

```
public function destroy(Team $team, Objective $objective, Deadline $deadline)
{
    //for deleting objective
    Objective::destroy($objective->id);
    Deadline::destroy($deadline->id);
    return redirect()->action([MonitorController::class, 'index',['team'=>$team]])->with('status', 'Objective Successfully Deleted');
}
```

here the index and destroy route

```
Route::get('/sistem/monitor/index/{team}', 'MonitorController@index');
Route::delete('/sistem/monitor/objective/details/{team}/{objective}', 'MonitorController@destroy');
```

Comment: You can do return redirect()->route('your_route_name')->with('status', 'Objective Successfully Deleted');

Comment: can you eleborate?
i try
return redirect()->route('sistem/monitor/index/team', 'MonitorController@index');
but i got 
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [/sistem/monitor/index/{team}] not defined.

Comment: I answered above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::get('/sistem/monitor/index/{team}', 'MonitorController@index')->name('sistem.monitor.index');
```

And in your controller:

```
return redirect()->route('sistem.monitor.index', ['team' => $team])->with('status', 'Objective Successfully Deleted');
```

Inside the route you should always pass the route name. In your route on web.php you specify a custom route name by doing: `->name('sistem.monitor.index')`

Comment: hi, thankyou for answering, i do exactly as you say, but now i got 
Missing required parameter for [Route: sistem.monitor.index] [URI: sistem/monitor/index/{team}] [Missing parameter: team].

Comment: Can you recheck, i upated it

Comment: im sorry, i cant upvote your answer since im new here